# Compact if/else statement [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3, syntax

Really simple question, I just wanted to know if there was a way to write if/else statements with fewer characters, for example I can create an if statement with either:

```
if (season == "autumn") {
  tree.gotoAndStop ("brown leaves");
}
```

or:

```
if (season == "autumn") tree.gotoAndStop ("brown leaves");
```

This uses much less space and makes my code look much prettier. With an if/else statement my options seem to be either:

```
if (season == "autumn" || season == "winter") {
  tree.gotoAndStop ("brown leaves");
} else {
  tree.gotoAndStop ("green leaves");
}
```

or:

```
gotoAndStop((season == "autumn" || season == "winter")
            ? "brown leaves" : "green leaves");
```

Though the second approach isn't always ideal. Do you know any alternatives?

Comment: Using fewer characters doesn't make the code better. It makes it harder to read, which is a detriment to code.

Comment: You can always leave off the braces if there is only one statement right after the if or else which is usually the way I go with it unless I'm using a ternary style operator for assignment.  Mostly agree with @zzzzBov generally reducing characters doesn't lead to clearer code which in the ends means a higher likelihood of bugs.  You can use FlexPrettyPrint plugin if you use FlashBuilder to format code to get a consistent readable format without much fiddling with space etc. while coding.

Comment: Alright, I'll take the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as writing your code in a terse manner, you can use all of the following techniques to manually minify your code, [***but this is a terrible design decision and will likely lead to headaches and/or bodily harm in the future***](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/coding-for-violent-psychopaths.html). Don't say I didn't warn you.

<sub>if-else:</sub>

```
if (foo) {
    bar();
} else {
    baz();
}
```

<sub>becomes:</sub>

```
foo?bar():baz()
```

<sub>if:</sub>

```
if (foo) {
    bar();
}
```

<sub>becomes:</sub>

```
foo&&bar();
```

<sub>if-not:</sub>

```
if (!foo) {
    bar();
}
```

<sub>becomes:</sub>

```
foo||bar();
```

<sub>if with multiple statements:</sub>

```
if (foo) {
    bar();
    baz();
    fizz();
    buzz();
}
```

<sub>becomes:</sub>

```
foo&&(bar(),baz(),fizz(),buzz());
```

Comment: "Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live."

Got it, I'll heed the warning.